# How are global static/non-static variables mangled in c?

Tags: c, name-mangling

I can imagine static variables `var` inside a function `func` to be named like `var@func`,

what about global static and non-static variables?

Comment: `var@func` would not be unique unless `func` is external... But anyway you're way off. Non-external variables and functions cease to have names at all once the compiler is finished with them.

Comment: @R.. ,sorry for the confusion.But where is static variables stored at all?You said it's only in the debug symbol table,which I doubt a lot. I think they should be in the symbol table used for resolving symbols

Comment: If you build with debugging information, automatic ("stack") variables have complex debugging information to describe their location relative to the stack pointer depending on the current instruction pointer. Otherwise they have no symbolic existence at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compilers don't need to uniquely name things with internal linkage, like static variables and functions. You can't access static objects outside the translation unit, so the linker doesn't need to get a name for them.

Global variables with external linkage don't usually have much mangling or decoration applied to their names, and it's often exactly the same that is applied to functions. A single leading underscore is not terribly uncommon.

Comment: @John Calsbeek,static variables are also restored in the symbol table,so you must have a name for it.

Comment: Whose symbol table? The assembler's?

Comment: @cpuer: Only the debugging symbol table. They're not stored in the symbol table used for resolving symbols and they are not mangled because they don't have names whatsoever.

Comment: @R.. ,do you mean all stuff that's generated by `gcc -g` is only stored in the debugging symbol table,not the symbol table used for resolving symbols(which deserves a separate table)?

Comment: @John, @R. my compilers behave differently from what you describe. `nm` clearly shows `static` variables even when compiled with `-O3`. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on that since the information given here is at least incomplete. Most compilers will create "local" symbol for static variables, and yes, since the naming of static variables in function scope is not unique, they have to mangle the names. gcc, e.g, does that by appending a dot and a unique number to the name. Since the dot is not part of any valid identifier, this makes sure that there is no name clash.

Things become obscure when the compiler supports universal characters in identifiers. Depending on the environment, the compiler has to mangle such identifiers, since e.g the loader might not support such characters in the symbol table.

icc chooses something like replacing such a character by _uXXXX where XXXX is the hex representation of the character. In that case (icc) this results in two subtle compiler bugs. First, this mangling uses valid identifiers that the user is allowed to use, so they may clash for global symbols with identifiers from the same compilation unit or even from other units. Second, icc even mixes up its own internal naming and reserves only space for one static variable and if they are eg also declared `volatile` completely runs into the wild.